# Why is there an NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c

If [`NSInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSInteger) is just like a regular `int` then why does it exist and what is its purpose in being called `NSInteger`?

I'm new to Mac OS X programming and we'll be having a report for this.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this question, @Tom Duckering!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's an architecture-safe (64 vs 32 bit) type to support different platforms and implementations of C.

Apple recommends that you use `NSInteger` over normal types anyway, I would assume for portability!

You can read more at this [Foundation Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).

Basic description:

> When building 32-bit applications,
>   NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A
>   64-bit application treats NSInteger as
>   a 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the typedef being different on different systems (`long` on 64-bit systems, `int` on 32-bit), there isn't much of a reason.

Arguably, it gives the impression that an `NSInteger` is an object, when it's not.

Comment: yeah, it actually confuses me with the other NS Classes

Answer (score 1):

A NSInteger will be 4 bytes on a 32-bit machine and 8 on a 64-bit.