# What is the difference between int and NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, types, int, nsinteger

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to use NSInteger vs int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int)
>   [Why is there is an NSInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870867/why-is-there-is-an-nsinteger)

Can we use `int` and `NSInteger` interchangably? Is there any specific situation to use `NSInteger` only, instead of using `int`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use NSInteger vs int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int), [How to Convert NSInteger to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752701/), or [Why is there an NSInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870867/), just three [among many](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsinteger+int).

Answer (score 20):

> Can we use int and NSInteger interchangably?

No.  On the LP64 architecture used by Apple, for modern OS X Cocoa, NSInteger is 64 bits wide.  This means that if you cast an NSInteger to an int, comparisons against [NSNotFound](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW3) may fail.  Here's an example:

```
NSRange theRange = [@"foo" rangeOfString @"x"];
int location = theRange.location;
if (location == NSNotFound) // comparison is broken due to truncation in line above
{
    // x not in foo
}
```

In my opinion, you should only use `NSInteger` where you need to pass a parameter to Cocoa or receive a result from Cocoa and the documentation says the data type is `NSInteger`.  In all other cases:

- if you don't care about the width of the type, use a C type e.g. `int` or `long`.
- if you do care about the width of the type, use the C99 `stdint.h` types e.g. `int32_t`, `int64_t`.
- if you need an int guaranteed big enough to hold a pointer, use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`

Comment: Also, if you need the difference between two pointers, you should be using `ptrdiff_t`, while for the size of an object in memory, `size_t` is appropriate.  And for offsets in files on disk, `off_t`.  All of this is basic C stuff, really.

Answer (score 2):

I would say use standard C99 uintptr_t for pointer sized integers. The definition of NSInteger looks sufficiently cloudy not to be sure it is guaranteed to hold a pointer.

Use NSInteger where the API uses it, if you must. But long will do for all practical purposes.

Looking at NSObjCRunTime, I don't really get the motivation for its current definition. Probably to have an integer type large enough to go up to, for instance, the maximum number of items in an NSArray?

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: No, use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` for pointer-sized integers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm too C++-98 (and wrong, in this case). Answer adjusted.