# what is diffrence between integerValue and intValue in objective C

Tags: objective-c

hi i am new to obj C and i am assigning a text field value to int variable PaidLeaves as below:
because text field return string value i have to cat it to int value so i use following code: 
for example

```
PaidLeaves = txtPaidLeaves.text.intValue;
```

and

```
PaidLeaves = txtPaidLeaves.text.integerValue;
```

above i am assigning a text field value to int value

and both works but what is difference between two expression

please tell me
thank you

Comment: One returns `int`, the other returns `NSInteger`. Use the one that actually matches the type you need.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056754/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-nsinteger Not sure if exact duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

- intValue returns an int number.
- integerValue returns a NSInteger number.

The difference between them is their number of bits, or in easier terms, the range of values that they can store. Has said in an answer of a different question:

> int is always 32-bits.
>
> long long is always 64-bits.
>
> NSInteger and long are always pointer-sized. That means they're
>   32-bits on 32-bit systems, and 64 bits on 64-bit systems.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4445467/4370893

Consider that Apple has only made 64 bit systems since Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), which was released in 2011, so I'm gonna refer to NSInteger has a 64 bit long integer.

***So what that means?***

The first bit of a signed integer number, like NSInteger and int, is used to define if it's a positive or a negative number. The conclusion is that a signed integer number goes from -2^(number of bits-1) to 2^(number of bits-1)-1, so...

- **int:** - 2,147,483,648 (- 2^31) to 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1)
- **NSInteger:** - 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 (- 2^63) to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (2^63-1)