# Why did happen EXC_BAD_ACCESS and SIGABRT when set integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access

I wrote code.

I want to save integer using nsuserdefault.

But this code happen EXC_BAD_ACCESS and SIGABRT.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [self desave:[newys integerValue] :[newms integerValue]];
    ...
}

...

- (void)desave:(NSInteger*)year :(NSInteger*)month//←EXC BAD ACCESS happened on this row.
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setInteger:year forKey:@"year"];//←SIGABRT happened on this row.

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace (`year` will almost certainly be `nil`, which is the problem).

Comment: So you chose to ignore the "incompatible pointer to integer conversion" compiler warnings?

Comment: I think there is some confusion between `NSNumber` and `NSInteger`; http://stackoverflow.com/q/5870867/620197

Comment: @martin +1 - symbolically since I accidentally undid my up vote and cannot up vote again as it seems :)

Comment: Not related, but please use standard naming conventions and name your parameters. `(void)desaveYear:(NSInteger*)year month:(NSInteger*)month` is definitely less awkward to read and use.

Comment: This seems like a pretty legit question over a misunderstanding of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your desave method signature, you're passing an NSInteger* as an argument where an NSInteger is expected. NSInteger is not an object derived from NSObject, it's a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the needless pointers being used for the `NSInteger` parameters.

Change:

```
- (void)desave:(NSInteger*)year :(NSInteger*)month
```

to:

```
- (void)desave:(NSInteger)year :(NSInteger)month
```

`NSInteger` is not a class type.

You should also name your method a little better. Right now the name is `desave::`. It would be better if it was:

```
- (void)desaveYear:(NSInteger*)year month:(NSInteger*)month
```

Now the name is `desaveYear:month:`.

And now you can call it with:

```
[self desaveYear:[newys integerValue] month:[newms integerValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a pointer to an `NSInteger`. The simplest way to solve this is:

```
- (void)desave:(NSInteger)year :(NSInteger)month
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:year forKey:@"year"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your method

```
- (void)desave:(NSInteger*)year :(NSInteger*)month
```

You are sending both year and month variables pointers. This sends the memory addresses instead. Try with this instead

```
- (void)desave:(NSInteger)year :(NSInteger)month
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:year forKey:@"year"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```