# Why did happened warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, warnings

I wrote code.

But its code happen warning.

Its warning text is

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSInteger *'
>   (aka 'int *') from 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

This is code that is causing the warning.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ...

    apd.newyear = [newys integerValue];//Its error happen on this row.

    apd.newmonth = [newms integerValue];//Its error happen on this row.

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Can you show what's `apd`?

Comment: Please show definition of apd, newys and newms.

Comment: Oh actually, it looks like you've defined a property as a pointer. i.e. `@property (nonatomic) int *newyear;` Just remove the *

Comment: It might help if you *read* and *understand* the answers to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338800/why-did-happen-exc-bad-access-and-sigabrt-when-set-integer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

`newyear` and `newmonth` both have type `NSInteger *` and you're trying to assign a `NSInteger` to them.

`NSInteger` is not an object, it's native C value, so you probably made a mistake in defining the two properties on your `apd` object.

I bet you have something like

```
@property NSInteger * newyear;
```

whereas it should be

```
@property NSInteger newyear;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your `NSInteger` instance variables as pointers, which they shouldn't be (they are not objects):

```
@interface apd : NSObject
{
    NSInteger *newyear;
    NSInteger *newmonth;
}
...
@end
```

(or you've done this via `@property`s):

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *newyear;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger *newmonth;
```

Just change them to plain `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've declared `newmonth` and `newyear` as pointers...

```
@property (nonatomic) int *newyear;
@property (nonatomic) int *newmonth;
```

Just remove the * from these lines.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might be useful..try it

`@interface abc : NSObject
{
    NSInteger firstint;
    NSInteger secondint;
}
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger firstint;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger secondint;
@end`